# Better way to pass many form input values from child to parent window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a child window which has a bunch of radio buttons. I would want to send all these many values to the opener window.

I am achieving this by appending all the input names and values to a javascript string. I am then using `window.opener` property to assign string to hidden field in parent window.

Code is like,

```
document.getElementById("Errnodata").innerHTML = "" ;  
var joinedArray = literal.join(", ");
window.opener.document.getElementById("myarray").value= joinedArray;
window.opener.getVolunteerDetails();
window.close();
```

So this means `joinedArray` string has form like `name1,value1,name2,value`. And is there any better way to pass many values to the parent window? Or any idiomatic/accepted way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lots of options. The parent window's `window` object is available to you (as you've found) via `window.opener`. The child window's `window` object is also availble to the parent, it's the return value of `window.open`. So the two can talk directly.

This means you can...

1. ...assign values to the parent directly, or (ideally) to an object it makes available on that for the purpose.

   In the parent:

   ```
   window.results = {};
   ```

   In the child:

   ```
   opener.results.name = "value";
   opener.results.anotherName = "another value";
   ```
2. ...or have the child window call a function on the parent:

   ```
   opener.callback(/*...values here...*/);
   ```

   ...passing in individual values, or an object, etc.
3. ...or have the parent window reach out and interact directly with the child's controls (but that creates a lot of tight coupling and I don't recommend it):

   ```
   // Assuming you did `var child = window.open(/*....*/);`
   var value = child.document.getElementById("someId").value;
   ```

---

Here's an example using a callback:

Parent: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ebohah/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ebohah/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Child Callback - Parent Window</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="btnOpen" value="Open Child Win">
  <script>
    (function() {
      var child;

      document.getElementById("btnOpen").onclick = function() {
        if (!child) {
          child = window.open("http://jsbin.com/ukuvaj/1");
        }
      };

      window.callback = function(value) {
        display("Got callback from child, value = " + value);
      };

      function display(msg) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = String(msg);
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Child: [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ukuvaj/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Child Window</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="textField" value="some value">
  <br><input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send to Parent">
  <script>
    (function() {
      document.getElementById("btnSend").onclick = function() {
        opener.callback(document.getElementById("textField").value);
      };
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1st approach looks reasonable for my use case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ahsan: Glad that helped. FWIW, I added an example using a callback, but the fundamental bits are the same.

Comment: Checking it. I appreciate your making it concise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass a string, you can pass anything to the opener window.  Below is some sample code you can use.  The parent opens the child, and the child sets some variables on the parent using object literal notation.

### Parent

```
    window.open('child.html');
    function showSettings() {
        // should say "hello"
        alert(myGlobalSettings.str);
    }
```

### Child

```
    window.opener.myGlobalSettings = {
        str: 'hello',
        array: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        obj: {
            x: 123
        }
    };
    window.opener.showSettings();
```

Answer (score 1):

**A clean method if you were using an IFRAME for the child**

Have the child form do a GET submission to itself and have the parent listen to the child frame's onload event and parse the data out of the new location.href 's query string.

parent.html

```
<textarea id="output_id"></textarea>
<iframe id="child_iframe_id" src="child.html"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframe = document.getElementById("child_iframe_id");
    iframe.onload = function() {
        var href = iframe.contentWindow.location.href;
        var result = "";
        var data;
        if(href.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
            data = href.split("?")[1].split("&");
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                var pair = data[i].split("=");
                result += decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) + " : ";
                result += decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) + "\n";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("output_id").value = result;
    }
</script>
```

child.html

```
<form id="child_id" method="get">
<input name="n1" />
<input name="n2" />
<select name="n3" >
<option value="v1">value</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="save to parent" />
</form>
```