# Getting array values of checkbox from iframe to parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i have this code which is suppose to get array values from iframe to the parent window

```
    $("#close_nr").bind("click", {page: this}, function (e) {
        var chkroomArr = new Array();
        $("input[name='name'].checked").each(function () {
            chkroomArr.push($(this).val());
            chkroomArr.toString();
            $("#RoomCategoryID", window.parent.document).val(chkroomArr);
        });
        $(".yui3-button-close", parent.document).trigger("click");
        $(".yui3-panel-content", parent.document).remove();
    });
```

how can i do this code to work because it is not passing the require value to the parent window. and how can i get the value to display went it is in the parent window
thanks in advance

Comment: check whether $("#RoomCategoryID", window.parent.document) object comes here..if not add one more parent d see

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in parent - window and call them instead of set value. E.g:

in parent window:

```
function SetValue(valToSet) {
   $("#RoomCategoryID").val(valToSet);
}
```

in "click" - event call

```
window.parent.SetValue(chkroomArr);
```

instead of

```
$("#RoomCategoryID", window.parent.document).val(chkroomArr);
```

**EDIT:**

For `$(".yui3-button-close", parent.document).trigger("click");
        $(".yui3-panel-content", parent.document).remove();`

also is better to create a function in parent - window and call it.

Comment: i created a function in the parent window and called it in the click event call but it complain of it not being a function, actually am working with phprunner. don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this question: [Better way to pass many form input values from child to parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682025/better-way-to-pass-many-form-input-values-from-child-to-parent-window)

if the URL of the iframe src is not in the same domain as the parent, there could be cross-domain security issues that prevent manipulation via javascript, as per the same-origin policies.